# Type 'any[]' cannot be used as an index type Angular build

Tags: angular, typescript

When I'm using `ng serve` everything works. When I use `ng serve --prod --aot` it complains with `Type 'any[]' cannot be used as an index type`. I could not find anything that could fix it. and the `type any[]` that it seems to be referring to is the tags variable because when I comment it out then everything compiles.

Here's the relevant code:

```
//cluster-details.component.ts
...
export class ClusterDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
infoTitles = {
    edgeNodePublicDNS: 'Edge Node Public DNS',
    ...
    tags: 'Tags'
};
infoKeys: string[];
info: any;
tags: any[];
...
this.requestsService.emrinstanceDetailsGET(body)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.infoKeys = Object.keys(data);
                this.info = data;
...
```

cluster-details.component.html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let key of infoKeys">
            <td>
                <strong>{{ infoTitles[key] }}:</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{info[key]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>{{ infoTitles[tags] }}:</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{tags}}
            </td>
        </tr>
```

And the request returns data like this:

```
.map(
      (response: Response) => {
          const data = response.json();
          return data['clusterDetail'];
```

Now I know that 'just don't make it type `any[]` but I couldn't figure out what to make it otherwise. What's returned is a JSON value that's just an Object type. Changing the type to Object didn't work and I don't see any other types that work. Maybe I'll have to make an interface for it?

Comment: The info variable is shown above as type `any`. Do you get the same error if you change it to `any[]`?

Comment: I do get the same error, same if I use Object or Object[]. It also still works on just `ng serve` with any of those four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Simple misusage of a variable that I didn't intend:

The HTML line `...{{ infoTitles[tags] }}...` is trying to index infoTitles with the tags variable - I meant for this to be a string that's just 'tags' wherein it will correctly reference the infoTitles value that I need. But I didn't catch that I'm using the tags array. So the fix should just be using a string or variable like `tagIndexString = 'tags'` then the HTML can be `...{{ infoTitles[tagIndexString] }}...`

Answer (score 0):

I believe AOT here cannot resolve your 'infoTitles' as you did not give it a specific type but used 'infoTitles[key]', object[name] (AOT takes for granted that you are using array syntax) later which caused the compilation error. Possible solution:

```
infoTitles: InfoTitle = {
    edgeNodePublicDNS: 'Edge Node Public DNS',
    ...
    tags: 'Tags'
};
```

You need to create a class:

```
export class InfoTitle {
    edgeNodePublicDNS: string;
    ...
    tags: string;
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix the error but the code still worked after adding it. I looked at the tags variable again and it seems to actually be there where the error is. The tags come in as an array of JSON objects and I try to parse them and display them as well. I'm going to see if I can't work at that to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, the same error was getting due to following code mistake, which is ignore by **'ng serve'** command:

**Code which gives error:**

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title={{subData[[col.field]]}}>{{subData[[col.field]]}}</span>
```

**Changed code to solve error:**

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title={{subData[col.field]}}>{{subData[col.field]}}</span>
```

**Just remove extra '[' from '[[' if your html code has.**